# How to set a custom global from .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, variables

Is there a way to set a custom variable from within `.htaccess` so that every php script can then read from it ? I went googling around nothing.

Thankyou!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can only set an environment variable from .htaccess:

```
SetEnv MYVAR whatever
```

And this becomes available in the [`$_SERVER`](http://php.net/_SERVER) array:

```
print $_SERVER["MYVAR"];
```

So, not exactly a global variable. But still useful for some purposes.

(The other option is declaring an `auto_prepend_file` to pre-define variables. But that's more a workaround then.)

Comment: +1 I learned something new. In what cases is it good practice to set an environment variable from the .htaccess file?

Comment: I'm mostly using this for declaring resource/path names. But in the end anything that could be considered a global site setting is okay.

Answer (score 6):

You can set environment variables in `.htaccess` (or `http.conf`):

```
SetEnv foo bar
```

and access them in PHP via

```
$_ENV['foo']
```

Answer (score 3):

if you want the variable accessible from the $_GET array (this will overwrite any variable being sent to the server thru get)

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1?%1&myvar=something
```

%1 whatever the query string might be

Comment: You might want to add `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !myvar` in front to prevent a infinite loop.

Answer (score 2):

How about using something like [mod_setenvif](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_setenvif.html#setenvif)?  Additional details available at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/env.html.

Answer (score 1):

I am using environment variables to tell me what part of the "5G Blacklist" firewall script http://perishablepress.com/5g-blacklist-2013/ is being triggered by a scumbag

For example, one part of the firewall stops the most common spammer query strings:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\"|%22).*(<|>|%3) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (javascript:).*(\;) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C).*script.*(>|%3) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\\|\.\./|`|=\'$|=%27$) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\;|\'|\"|%22).*(union|select|insert|drop|update|md5|benchmark|or|and|if) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (base64_encode|localhost|mosconfig) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (boot\.ini|echo.*kae|etc/passwd) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (GLOBALS|REQUEST)(=|\[|%) [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [E=BadQueryString,F]
```

See that E=BadQueryString ? I added that. The syntax of course must be precise.

Then in my PHP program for handling 403: Permission denied errors, I use it this way (notice this server prepends "REDIRECT_" to the environment variable name):

```
if (getenv("REDIRECT_BadQueryString") !== FALSE) {
  $htaccessErrors .= ' BadQueryString';
  if (getenv("REDIRECT_QUERY_STRING") !== FALSE) {
    $htaccessErrors .= getenv("REDIRECT_QUERY_STRING");
  }     
}
```

Here is another .htaccess example, testing the User-Agent server variable and using the environment variable if it was set, and then the environment variable is available in my 403.php

```
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent (binlar|casper|cmsworldmap|comodo|diavol|dotbot|feedfinder|flicky|ia_archiver|kmccrew|nutch|planetwork|purebot|pycurl|skygrid|sucker|turnit|vikspider|zmeu) BadUserAgent
<limit GET POST PUT>
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all
Deny from env=BadUserAgent
</limit>
```