# Magento - Hide prices based on IP

Tags: magento

I am due to put a Magento site live and the client has sprung a last minute request. They are a UK based manufacturer and they don't want to compete with their worldwid supply chain, so they want;

1. All users with IPs originating in North America get redirected to a totally different website (non-Magento, nothing to do with me) ideally with a redirect message.
2. All user with IPs originating anywhere other than North America, The UK and Ireland get to see the site but with the pricing and cart disabled so they don't see prices and can't make a purchase
3. UK and Ireland operate as normal.

I'm trying to work out the best way to approach this.  I am aware of three options;

- **.HTACCESS**

I've worked on a store before where the developer has set a huge list of IPs in the .htaccess (mainly blocking China and Russia as a security thing).  I could do something similar, redirecting users with USA IPs and then maybe setting an environmental variable like so;

[How to set a custom global from .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8781181/how-to-set-a-custom-global-from-htaccess)

Which could be accessed in the templates to not display the add to cart and price markup.

***Pros:*** Relatively Easy

***Cons:*** Horrible. The list of IPs would be hardcoded, and the conditional code to display/not display the prices etc would be template based rather than done via a module.  Plus the 'You are being transferred to our USA store' request couldn't be handled this way.

- **Store switching using commercial module**

Another option could be to customise/configure the following commercial module to handle the request;

http://www.mageworx.com/store-and-currency-auto-switcher-magento-extension.html

I'm thinking this would involve setting up new websites rather than new stores (as the current installation already has 1 Website and 2 Stores each with one Store View.).  The new websites would have their own theme with no cart/price info displayed.

***Pros:*** IPs not hardcoded, uses the MaxMind GeoIP database.  Module based.
***Cons:*** Again the code whether to display the Prices is template based. Also this would add a lot of administration overhead for the user - extra websites, extra store views to complicate things.  And not using 99% of the features of this module.

- **A Custom Module to handle it**

I know this is the ideal solution but I am much happier in app/design than I am in app/code.  I know how to build a module and have built very small modules before but....   Based on Alan Storm's blog post here;

http://magento-quickies.tumblr.com/post/32402056167/magento-startup-events

I am imagining I would use the `controller_front_init_before` event and create an observer which extends a class or classes  relating to the isSaleable() method which is used in the product view templates anyway. Possibly??

***Pros:***  This is the right way to do it. No admin overhead.  Easy to disable/enable.

Any suggestions, pointers or links on this would be a big help.  Thanks.

Comment: You can avoid hardcoding addresses with the .htaccess method by installing [mod_geoip](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/mod_geoip2) on the server.

Comment: It's not your fault, but this is an absolutely inane idea from your client. I hope you did your due diligence as their consultant and tried to explain why this is ultimately pointless and likely to cost them more to maintain than to deal with otherwise.

Comment: RE the last option: It's always good to consider hooking an event, but the solution as you state it deviates pretty far from separation of concerns and will be quite cumbersome as the front controller event is dispatched before the application has determined its execution context, i.e., there is no awareness at that point that the request will result in prices being displayed. You also have to handle the various contexts in which prices are displayed.

Comment: Tks guys - @benmarks , I did not tbh - I've never dealt with this type of issue before at all, although I've read a few non-magento SO questions on it (and the answers saying don't bother!). On this job I'm once removed from the client so its a case of making the best job of a dodgy remit unfortunately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a kick-off for what you called an "ideal solution".

Get my free GeoIP extension from [MagnetoConnect](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/catalog/product/view/id/14060/) or [GitHub](https://github.com/openstream/geoip). Then in any template use:

```
$geoIP = Mage::getSingleton('geoip/country');
...
<?php if($geoIP->isCountryAllowed()) ?>
    the block of code you want to display only for selected countries
<?php endif ?>
```

More info in my article [here](http://www.openstream.ch/developer-blog/magento-geoip-extension-2/).

If you have any question please feel free to ask.

Comment: Totally missed your module in my searching, thanks Tim. This looks ideal, I will down load and try it out.

Comment: This is spot on Tim, fantastic. Easily managed via the backend too, great stuff. Not that I doubt your skills for a minute but any tips on how to test it? Would it be using some proxy / cloaking service?

Comment: I'm using proxies to work with it. Or you can disallow your current country to see if it is working.