# Retrieve link created by htacces file using php

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

I am trying to retrieve an url form the Adress bar in a joomla enviroment.

The URL´s are put together with HTACCES i think.. Wich causes url to look like this:

```
www.myadress.com/webshop/category/shopitem/flypage.tpl.php
```

Now when i use a server request URI it will give me something like this:

```
/index.php?option=com_virtuemart&Itemid=41&category_id=25&flypage=flypage.tpl&lang=nl&limitstart=0&page=shop.product_details&product_id=59
```

Anybody that can help me with this?
I need it to build a custom crumbmenu..

Comment: Try `print_r($_SERVER)` and see if you find the value you’re looking for in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on the server but sometimes these are available.

```
$_SERVER['REDIRECT_SCRIPT_URL']

$_SERVER['REDIRECT_SCRIPT_URI']
```

If that does not work I would try setting a custom global from .htaccess as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8781181/how-to-set-a-custom-global-from-htaccess) in another question.