# PHP - Get IP when page calling by htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, get, ip

I have a website in PHP and need to know what the IP of the accessing client is. For this I am using the function below:

```
function get_client_ip() {
    $ipaddress = '';
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    } elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    } else {
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }

    return $ipaddress;
}
```

But when accessing the site by url omenorpreco.com/teste the page returns the server IP.

When access to page the url omenorpreco.com/teste.php, the page returns the client IP.

Possibly this error occurs because when you access the page without the extension ".php", the server interprets the page by .htaccess?

How can I adjust my application for both accesses, return the client's IP, and not the server IP?

above my htaccess code

```
    php_value allow_url_fopen on
    php_value allow_url_include 1
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule !.(js|ico|txt|gif|bmp|jpeg|jpg|png|css|log|rss|zip|xml|sql|pdf|doc|docx|xls)$ url_amigavel.php
    RewriteRule sitemap-categoria.xml$ sitemap.php?number=categoria
    RewriteRule sitemap-([0-9]+).xml$ sitemap.php?number=$1
    RewriteRule sitemap_index.xml$ sitemap_index.php
```

and url_amigavel.php code

```
<?php

$geturl = explode( "/", str_replace( strrchr( $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], "?" ), "", $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] ) );
array_shift( $geturl );

$tipo = $geturl[0];


if ( is_file( "$tipo.php" ) )
{
    include "$tipo.php";
}
else
{
    echo "page not found";

}

?>
```

EDIT: CAN I SET GLOBAL_VAR IN HTACCESS WITH THE CLIENT IP?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the client IP address in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003145/how-to-get-the-client-ip-address-in-php)

Comment: How does your application handle url routing..

Comment: @rjdown OP is not asking how to?

Comment: Add the `.htaccess` file contents to you post. It seems (by the echoing of 1 line on one URL and 2 on another) that routing to a different script may be a culpret

Comment: I include my .htaccess in this post.

Comment: Could you post the contents of `url_amigavel.php` (url_friendly.php) please?

Comment: included the url_amigavel code..

Comment: You could try and set a global var (like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8781208/5663450)) to `HTTP:X-FORWARDED-FOR` and see if that works. Worth a shot

Comment: i tried SetEnv IPCLIENT $_SERVER("REMOTE_ADDR"), but the var IPCLIENT  return a string $_SERVER("REMOTE_ADDR")  =/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I just saw it work on your server!
Change `.htaccess` to;

```
php_value allow_url_fopen on
php_value allow_url_include 1

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule !.(js|ico|txt|gif|bmp|jpeg|jpg|png|css|log|rss|zip|xml|sql|pdf|doc|docx|xls)$ url_amigavel.php
RewriteRule sitemap-categoria.xml$ sitemap.php?number=categoria
RewriteRule sitemap-([0-9]+).xml$ sitemap.php?number=$1
RewriteRule sitemap_index.xml$ sitemap_index.php

SetEnvIfNoCase Remote_Host "(.*)" HTTP_MY_REMOTE_HOST=$1
SetEnvIfNoCase Remote_Addr "(.*)" HTTP_MY_REMOTE_ADDR=$1
```

An change `test.php` to;

```
function get_client_ip() {
    if (isset($_SERVER[REDIRECT_HTTP_MY_REMOTE_ADDR])) {
        return $_SERVER[REDIRECT_HTTP_MY_REMOTE_ADDR];

    } else if (isset($_SERVER[REDIRECT_HTTP_MY_REMOTE_HOST])) {
        return $_SERVER[REDIRECT_HTTP_MY_REMOTE_HOST];

    } else if (isset($_SERVER[HTTP_MY_REMOTE_ADDR])) {
        return $_SERVER[HTTP_MY_REMOTE_ADDR];

    } else if (isset($_SERVER[HTTP_MY_REMOTE_HOST])) {
        return $_SERVER[HTTP_MY_REMOTE_HOST];

    }
}

echo get_client_ip();
```

Inspiration for setting variables in `.htaccess` from: http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/setenvif.html

Glad it finally worked!

Comment: I think a trailing slash left over might have been a cause for the `404`, try my updated answer if the previous one does not work

Comment: Darn. Try putting `echo $tipo;` before the `if` statement to see where the file is being requested from

Comment: $tipo.php is the file where your get_client_ip function is?

Comment: Hmm, seems right, think my solution makes no difference.

Comment: can you var_dump ($geturl);

Comment: I'm pretty much out of options, try commenting out the `php_value allow_url_fopen on` and `php_value allow_url_include 1` flags in `.htaccess`, might be some weird external request initiation somewhere

Comment: Yeh `$geturl` won't contain the domain, my mistake xD . So we think the correct PHP file is run, but somewhere along the line the IP address is changed to the server only when that `.htaccess` rewrite rule is run?Strange. I've gotta sleep now good luck aarron and Rodrigo :)

Comment: var_dump($geturl) = array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "test2" }

Comment: i commented these lines in .htaccess and the result is the same =/
thakyou for try to helpme, goodnight

Comment: Morning all, Rodrigo - did you try my suggestion of commenting out/ removing the two allow php flags in your .htaccess file? David Alvarez has now suggested this too as a possible cause

Comment: Morning Benjy. I aswrer in a David propose to solve this problem.

Comment: Tried again.. Have many diferences between my page and yours =/

Comment: OK, my final guess is posted - hopefully it should work

Comment: Finally!!!!! Thank you so much. When i set variable in htaccess i can get the correct IP from client.. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

Put this in a file and run with and without the extension:

```
<?php
function get_ip_address() {
    return $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}
    echo get_ip_address();

?>
```

What error do you get if you run the above?

EDIT:
Can you edit your .htaccess like this and see if the error still occurs:

```
php_value allow_url_fopen on
php_value allow_url_include 1
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule !.(js|ico|txt|gif|bmp|jpeg|jpg|png|css|log|rss|zip|xml|sql|pdf|doc|docx|xls)$ $1.php [L]
RewriteRule sitemap-categoria.xml$ sitemap.php?number=categoria
RewriteRule sitemap-([0-9]+).xml$ sitemap.php?number=$1
RewriteRule sitemap_index.xml$ sitemap_index.php
```

Comment: Hi stirredo.

You can acess this pages?


http://omenorpreco.com/test2.php
http://omenorpreco.com/test2

i put your code into this page to test.. acess and see the error..

the first link retorn a correct ip
the second link return a server ip

the second link access the page test2.php by the htaccess.

Comment: The webpage doesn't load for me. Can you check the server setting again please.

Comment: i ajust my file test2.php, and the result is the same.. could you access?

Comment: I am not able to access the page, it says "This webpage is not available".

Comment: I am able to access it, the IP address issue still remains. Seems like a fresh request is made by the server or `url_amigavel.php` does something  significant (asked to post it).

Comment: strange because I have not blocking ip or region on my website.He tried to put www in front?

Comment: I had to use a proxy to access your website (probably problem at my end) and saw what you meant. Like Benjy said, please post the contents of url_amigavel.php

Comment: i chaged to RewriteRule !\.(js|ico|txt|gif|bmp|jpeg|jpg|png|css|log|rss|zip|xml|sql|pdf|doc|docx|xls)$ $1.php [L] and now return another error.. because (***) is a extension.. could you see?

Answer (score 0):

You have allow_url_include set to 1 on your .htaccess. This is causing problems because as you are telling PHP to include a file, the preprocessor thinks it's a URL, other people have told you this so let's go straight.

My guess is, just disable allow_url_include. It's a bad practice, a security risk and there's nothing you can't do just with file_get_contents for example.

If you are still convinced that including remote files is a good idea, you should try using a full path, using this include with the code Benjy1996 gave you:

`include(getcwd().$tipo.".php");`

PD: you should probably change your ip function to return $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] only as well, as it's the one you can trust the most, because it's the most difficult to fake.

Comment: Hello Benjy / David - I tried to change my htaccess, removing two lines of php value settings, and input the code <pre>include ( getcwd()."/". $tipo . ".php");</pre> into url_amigavel.php, and doesnt work two. =(

Comment: I've just done a carbon copy of your original `.htaccess`, `test.php` and `url_amigavel.php` on my server and its providing expected results [ets.16mb.com/test](http://ets.16mb.com/test) and [ets.16mb.com/test.php](http://ets.16mb.com/test.php). It seems something must be configured differently somewhere.

Comment: WOW.. =( you just copy my original files? I access your server and really work fine.. Maybe its a server configuration?

Comment: Yeh your original code works :). Its some configuration somewhere. Can you think of anything that could cause this? Any framework you are using or other configurations that have been set?

Comment: I think I may have found a possible cause, just check for the `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']` field, ignoring `REMOTE_ADDR`, sometimes `.htaccess` can change this field with `RewriteRule`s

Comment: I have no idea , because the server that I use is a paid server , and who run it are a great company in Brazil , which does not allow me to change settings. I can make a request to look at the problem, but must be specific , otherwise not act on the problem.

Comment: the variable $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] is empty.. 
http://omenorpreco.com/test2

Comment: I'll move back to my post XD